# unresolved linker errors for many windows functions in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt

In Qt, I am getting unresolved linker errors for many windows functions such as `SHGetKnownFolderPath`

```
#include "pip.h"
#include "ui_pip.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <Objbase.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Knownfolders.h>
```

Function:

```
PWSTR appData = 0;

    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop,
                                   0,
                                   NULL,
                                   &appData)))
{
    wcout << appData << endl;
}
```

Linker Error:

```
pip.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SHGetKnownFolderPath@16 
referenced in function "private: void __thiscall pip::on_submitButton_clicked(void)" 
(?on_submitButton_clicked@pip@@AAEXXZ)
```

Do I need to tell QT where the `Shell32.dll` library is or something for `shlobj.h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **link** your project with the **library** (*shell32.lib*) that implements that symbol!

You should add something like the following to the .PRO file:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\\Path\\Microsoft SDK\\Windows\\v7.1\\Lib" -lshell32
```

Comment: The explicit path after `-L` is not necessary, Qt has to link with windows libraries anyway so it's there. `-lshell32` is sufficient.