# Qt: windows functions are unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, qt-creator

I'm trying to compile a simple helloworld-like non-Qt C++ application using te WinAPI in QtCreator. Here's the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND cons = GetConsoleWindow();
    SetWindowText(cons, L"I am the console window");
    MessageBox(cons, L"Hello world!", L"I am the MessageBox", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
```

Looks very simple, but when I've tried to build it, the compilation fails with:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxW@16 referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetWindowTextW@8 referenced in function _main
```

I started to seek, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336325/unresolved-linker-errors-for-many-windows-functions-in-qt), but it wasn't helping me at all, because when I had written this:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Lib"
```

and even this:

```
LIBS += -L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Lib\\shell32.lib"
```

in my `.pro`, these "symbols" still stand unresolved. I ran qmake after **each change** to the `.pro`-file contents. So, any ideas?

Comment: You definitely miss linkage to a Windows library. Maybe `user32.lib`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-L` sets the search paths for DLLs, but it doesn't actually link anything. The actual linking is done via `-l`. Setting the search path for system libraries shouldn't be necessary, but you'll need to link against user32:

```
win32:LIBS += -luser32
```

Comment: It makes the rest of the line Windows-specific (in case you ever want to build your project somewhere else)

Answer (score 5):

Additional to Frank's answer (which helped me very much, thanks for that!) I would like to add that this is only required vor MSVC, MinGW doesn't seem to need that line. Which was for me the most confusing part, I first thought I had problems with the msvc toolchain.

My inclusion now looks like this to reflect this fact:

```
msvc: LIBS += -luser32
```